# Connecting to redis using redisson library throws "Unable to Decode Data"?

Tags: redis, grpc, netty, redisson

I just migrated from spring.data.redis to the Redisson library for redis implementation in my spring boot project. And while creating the Redisson instance facing an "Unable to Decode Data" error. And the error log is,

*[time][redisson-netty-2-3] Error[..] - Unable to decode data. Channel:[...]*

which results,
org.redisson.client.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to Redis Server:10.XX.XXX.XXX

Code we have tried is,

In build.gradle:
...
implementation ('org.redisson:redisson:3.20.1')
...

And While creating the redisson object as below,
In Config File

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig

@Bean
public RedisConfig getRedis(){
   ....
   Config config = new Config();
   config.useSingleServer()
       .setAddress("myAddress")
       .setPasseord("password")
       .setTrustStore("truststoreUrl")
       .setTrustStorePassword("trustStorePassword")
       .setConnectionPoolSize(24)

   RedissonClient redissonClient = Resisson.create(config);   //Error causing line
  .................
}
```

We are expected to redisson instance to be created but we are facing above error.